# Who is responsible to set the To WS(Ws-Addressing) namespace in SOAP header in an outgoing message?

Tags: c#, web-services

I have a created a .Net client to access a Webservice. The SOAP request xml generated in client side constructs with WS-Addressing namespace as “xmlns:wsa=http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing.”, but in the Service side it expects WS-Addressing namespace as “xmlns:wsa=http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing”. How we can configure correct WS-Addressing namespace in request. Help me to resolve this issue?

Comment: How are you creating the client? "Add Service Reference"?

Answer (score 0):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.channels.messageversion.aspx), there are two versions for WS addressing: the Aug 10 2004 version, and the 'official' version. I think you'll have to create a custom binding to specify the soap addressing version:

```
<bindings>
    <customBinding name="CorrectSoapBinding">
        <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap12WSAddressing10"/>
  </customBinding>
</bindings>
```